# Want to use Bash & Regex to replace comma in file

Tags: regex, linux, bash, csv, replace

I need to replace a specific character, like comma, in a csv file.

I have files with text and numeric separated by ';' (csv as French...)

Example:

```
value;x;y;comment;
abc;123,45;987,65;abc;
abc;123.45;987.65;abc;
abc;123,45;987,65;abc, blabla;
```

There is a mix for the decimal separator , both ',' and '.' are used.

I want to replace ',' by '.' but ONLY for decimal values, not text like comments.

I tried sed with regex

```sh
sed -i '/;[0-9]\+,[0-9]\+;/s/,/./g' file.csv
```

But that replace all comma. I can't found how to replace only what I want.

I want to do that only in bash.

Comment: This is much simpler with a proper CSV parser, available in the standard library of many other languages. You should also limit the replacements to fields that are known to contain numerical data, not all fields. If you don't have a proper CSV parser, at least use `awk`, which can work with individual fields more easily than `sed`.

Comment: Why regexes specifically? If you use tools like `sed`, that's no longer "only bash", as `/bin/sed` is a completely separate executable. bash has built-in string manipulation tools you don't need external commands for; these are often based on fnmatch-style matching rather than regular expressions, but that doesn't mean they're unsuited for the use case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One `sed` idea using extended regex and capture groups:

```
sed -E 's/([0-9]),([0-9])/\1.\2/g' file.csv
```

Where:

- `-E` - enable extended regex support
- `([0-9]),([0-9])` - match a single digit + `,` + single digit
- `([0-9])` - define a capture group (there are 2 capture groups in this case)
- `\1.\2` - print capture group #1 + `.` + capture group #2

This generates:

```
value;x;y;comment;
abc;123.45;987.65;abc;
abc;123.45;987.65;abc;
abc;123.45;987.65;abc, blabla;
```

**NOTES**:

- once OP is satisfied the code performs the desired operation the `-i` flag can be added to have `sed` perform an in-place update of the file
- this will erroneously replace the comma in a string such as `;3,2,4 five 6,7 eight ;` (this can be addressed but will require a more complex regex)

Answer (score 2):

You may use this simpler `sed`:

```sh
sed -i.bak -E 's/([0-9]),([0-9])/\1.\2/g' file

value;x;y;comment;
abc;123.45;987.65;abc;
abc;123.45;987.65;abc;
abc;123.45;987.65;abc, blabla;
```

**Details:**

- `([0-9]),([0-9])`: Match a digit followed by comma followed by a digit. Capture before and after digits in capture group #1 and #2
- `\1.\2`: Replace with back-reference #1 followed by dot followed by back-reference #2

---

**Alternatively**, you may use this more robust `awk` solution:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=";"} {for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) 
if ($i ~ /^[0-9]+,[0-9]+$/) sub(/,/, ".", $i)} 1' file

value;x;y;comment;
abc;123.45;987.65;abc;
abc;123.45;987.65;abc;
abc;123.45;987.65;abc, blabla;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
sed -i 's/;\([0-9]\+\),\([0-9]\+\)/;\1.\2/g' file.csv
```

Note: if you use the `-i` option, don't forget to make a backup of your original data, just in case.

Comment: -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]

              edit files in place (makes backup if SUFFIX supplied)